# C++: Crash when compiling with gcc 9.1, 9.2 with any level of optimization

Tags: crash

The following code crashes if compiled with gcc.9.1 and 9.2. If compiled with older gcc everything is ok.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        set( nullptr );
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t offset_;

    void set( void* ptr )
    { 
        offset_ = reinterpret_cast<char*>( ptr ) - reinterpret_cast<char*>( this );
    }

    void* get()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>( this ) + offset_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    int *b = static_cast<int*>( a.get() );

    if( !b )
        a.set( b = new int{ 10 } );

    return *b;
}
```

Link to the code on the coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f5b4623a98fd0b5

Looking to the assembler I see that gcc eliminates the `if` statement. Link to the godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/HrX3Uc

So the question is:
Is it a bug in the gcc which needs to be reported or my program contains some UB ?

Answer (score -1):

```
struct A
{
    A()
    {
        set( this );
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t offset_;

    void set( void* ptr )
    { 
        offset_ = reinterpret_cast<char*>( this ) - reinterpret_cast<char*>( ptr );
    }
    bool hasValue()
    {
        return offset_ != 0;
    }
    void* get()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>( this ) - offset_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    int *b = static_cast<int*>( a.get() );

    // nullptr != 0
    if(!a.hasValue())
        a.set( b = new int{ 10 } );

    return *b;
}
```